# imagemagick - downsize/crop/save to jpeg in one go?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I have a php script that will receive a bunch of images uploaded.

What I need to do is create a small thumbnail of each, on the fly using imagemagick.

I can do that easy enough but I also need to crop it so that the thumbnail is always 100x100.

the images supplied won't be the same proportions so simply downsizing won't work.

Can I downsize, crop to 100x100 and save to jpeg all in one step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want:

```
convert 'just_uploaded/*' -resize 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100 -set filename:f '%t' +adjoin 'just_uploaded_thumbs/%[filename:f].jpg'
```

`resize` will downsize, `extent` (in combination with `gravity`) will crop, and the rest takes care of saving with a modified name, in JPEG format, in a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. That'll be 3 steps, no less.

Longer answer: you can do it using the command line interface. In PHP, the only way is to write a function that will do what you ask. Then, for each image, you can just call your function. I'm not sure how this is more beneficial than just using the 3 Imagick functions separately...

Answer (score 0):

I like the sfThumbnailPlugin. It wraps around both ImageMagick or GD

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfThumbnailPlugin

Example:

```
public function executeUpload()
{
  // Retrieve the name of the uploaded file
  $fileName = $this->getRequest()->getFileName('file');

  // Create the thumbnail
  $thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(150, 150);
  $thumbnail->loadFile($this->getRequest()->getFilePath('file'));
  $thumbnail->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/thumbnail/'.$fileName, 'image/png');

  // Move the uploaded file to the 'uploads' directory
  $this->getRequest()->moveFile('file', sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$fileName);

  // Do whatever is next
  $this->redirect('media/show?filename='.$fileName); 
}
```